# Arabic reading error

Tags: flash, internationalization, arabic, rtl

I can't read Arabic correctly (from Right to Left) when using Firefox to open Flash websites in Ubuntu 10.10

[image]

example: http://www.fpnp.net/

Please I need help, thanks...

Comment: please i need help :(

Comment: I don't read Arabic, so I'm not sure what you're seeing as wrong.  The Arabic shows up in the Flash part of the page in your screenshot (the part with the two men), and it looks like it's written right-to-left to me...or at least, it's displayed exactly the same as on Windows.

Comment: @maco, almost 4 years old question :). On bottom right corner, Even the alignment is to the right, letter are in reverse order (noway to know if you don't know the meaning, If I wasn't knowing English how could I know `pleh` is reversed). Another aspect, Arabic is a cursive script. those two line have separated letters, see in bottom left red backgrounded phrase, like lines connecting letters. As I know, this a bug in Flash (Need to support Unicode BiDi and Shaping). I just want to mention here, so this question will be informative.

Answer (score 2):

That site appears to work fine in my Firefox for me on 10.10. Have you definitely got Flash installed? (From a command line `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`).

Perhaps if you are still having problems you could post a screenshot to give us a better idea of the problem?

Comment: that affects me too. the letters on the down right part of the screen are not connected and go from left to right. which makes it impossible to read. i'm looking for an answer also. flash 10.2 installed and ff.4 with ubuntu maverick

Comment: {UPDATE} This problem is in ubuntu 11.04, iam thinking to switch to windows

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a Flash bug and will also display incorrectly if you try the same site on Windows. (The problem is that none of the Arabic letters are connected to each other in the bottom right of the screen.)

Comment: and the letters are not in order. (not right to left but left to right)

Comment: This problem is not in fedora or even wnidows

Comment: Ok, you're right, the site does work on Windows. As Flash is closed source, we don't have the ability to really troubleshoot it very well.

Comment: So, this problem doesnt have a way to fix it ?? , is that what you mean?