# Right-to-Left script fail with Flash Player

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, flash, language-support, arabic

I am continuing an abandoned thread [Arabic reading error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6485/arabic-reading-error), since it was not solved.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, Firefox 3.6.14. I've checked for Flash Player, I have the recent version installed.

In the Flash Player window arabic script appears in wrong direction. The letters are displayed from left to right and not, as it should be, from right to left. For exemple http://www.fpnp.net/. The problematic place is the black bar in Flash window with a text below the image on the right. Here the letters are displayed in wrong direction and, by consequence, are not joined. You can see (I hope) the difference between that black bar and the rest of the text.

[image: picture of the problem]

Hope it will understandable for not Arabic-speaking people.

Thanks

Comment: I think nobody will find a solution for this problem.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579410/arabic-letters-shown-disconnected-in-flash and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339436/reversed-and-separated-farsi-arabic-characters-in-adobe-flash-on-ubuntu-64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579410/arabic-letters-shown-disconnected-in-flash/1713696#1713696), the problem is due to a shortcoming of the version of Adobe Flash that the web developer used.

There are no known user workarounds. The problem must be corrected by the web developer.